# Disable action for specific entries

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

In Sonata Admin, in one of my section, I would like to disable the delete action for 4 specific entries/lines.

I know I can do it for the entire listing with `configureRoutes()` but couldn't find anything for specific entries.
I tried the following but `getSubject()` is always empty.

```
protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
{
    $product = $this->getSubject();
    if ($product && $product->getIsBase())
    {
        $collection->clearExcept(array('list', 'edit'));
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override the `isGranted` method in your admin class:

```
public function isGranted($name, $object = null)
{
    if (in_array($name, array('LIST', 'EDIT')) && $object && $object->getIsBase()) {
        return false;
    }

    return parent::isGranted($name, $object);
}
```

Comment: Almost what I need. I only need to disable the delete action so I did `if (in_array($name, array('DELETE')) && $object && $object->getIsBase())` which works good, thanks. However, I still can delete my line via the bulk actions :(

Comment: In this case you may disable bulk deletion at all or (if you need bulk actions) extend the CRUD controller with your own one and override a bulk action method